# Update or merge map

Tags: elixir

Let's say I have this map

```
old = %{stuff: %{old: 123}}
```

How do I update the key `stuff:`?

I have this other map:

```
new = %{stuff: %{new: 321}}
```

With Map.put it will override stuff key and I also tried Map.merge but it doesnt merge, it overrides the key with the second map

```
iex(22)> Map.merge(test, new)
%{stuff: %{new: 321}}
```

I would like to have something like:

```
%{stuff: %{old: 123, new: 321}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ways I can think of:

1. Use `update_in`:

   ```
   iex(1)> old = %{stuff: %{old: 123}}
   %{stuff: %{old: 123}}
   iex(2)> update_in(old, [:stuff], &Map.put(&1, :new, 321))
   %{stuff: %{new: 321, old: 123}}
   ```
2. Use `Map.merge/3` which merges the two values using `Map.merge/2`:

   ```
   iex(3)> new = %{stuff: %{new: 321}}
   %{stuff: %{new: 321}}
   iex(4)> Map.merge(old, new, fn k, v1, v2 -> Map.merge(v1, v2) end)
   %{stuff: %{new: 321, old: 123}}
   ```

Comment: Also 3. `{_, result} = Map.get_and_update(%{stuff: %{old: 123}}, :stuff, fn cv -> {cv, Map.merge(cv, %{new: 456})} end)`.

Comment: Also `%{old | stuff: Map.merge(old.stuff, new.stuff)}`